# what is the disadvantage of <!doctype html>

Tags: html

Are there any disadvantages if i replace doctype

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

to

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is a HTML 5 doctype declaration,

while `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` is an **HTML 4.01 Transitional declaration**.

> This DTD contains all HTML elements and attributes, INCLUDING presentational and deprecated elements (like font). Framesets are not allowed.

So if you are using any deprecated elements from HTML 4.01, they won't work anymore when you switch to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. But if you're just keeping yourself to HTML 5 standards, you're fine. Normally you won't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks Rizky, will it be also  effect on SEO?

Comment: @satishmaurya It doesn't. The formatting of your code does not help rank your page. Only the content of your page will influence your rankings. The tags in the HTML code only make it easier for search engines to interpret the page (For example, find the content of your page).

Answer (score 0):

According to [WHATWG](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_DOCTYPE_for_modern_HTML_documents.3F) `<!DOCTYPE html>` is recommended because it triggers standard mode in all browsers, including legacy ones. The other doctype you mentioned has simply no use anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A "Document Type Declaration" is an SGML concept for signalling the mark-up syntax and vocabulary for the mark-up that follows. `<!DOCTYPE html>` does not conform to the requirements of that.

This is unlike `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` which is a SGML conforming Document Type Declaration.

[Difference in rendering different doctypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types) will help you in understanding the difference in depth.